# Syntax higlight in codemirror

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var id = '<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>';
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(id), {
            mode: "application/xml",
            lineNumbers: true,
            buttons : ['undo','redo'],
            onCursorActivity: function() {
                editor.setLineClass(hlLine, null);
                hlLine = editor.setLineClass(editor.getCursor().line, "activeline");
            }
        });
        var hlLine = editor.setLineClass(0, "activeline");
    });

</script>
```

Code works fine but unable to highlight syntax and button is not appear.Am i missing something.Thanks.

Comment: Should "hlLine" be in quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's is on `buttons` option in CodeMirror. If things don't highlight, you probably forgot to include a stylesheet.